# MySQL combine two SELECT queries into one checking for duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Given these two simple queries:

```
SELECT materialID FROM materials WHERE compoundNumber = "<some user input1>";
SELECT materialID FROM materials WHERE vendorCompoundNumber = "<some user input2>";
```

How can I make them into one query with the result set look something like this:

```
materialID | compoundDupFound | vendorCompoundDupFound

1          |                0 |                      1

              - - or - -

2          |                1 |                      0 

              - - or - -

3          |                1 |                      1
```

I realize I can perform one then the other but I'm wondering if there is a clever built in way to construct a query to do both at once.

The columns compoundNumber & vendorCompoundNumber need to be unique in the database so I'm checking a form and making sure the user inputs something unique. I will display an error message based on the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use the `OR` operator to combine queries

```
SELECT materialID, compoundNumber AS compoundDupFound, vendorCompoundNumber AS vendorCompoundDupFound
FROM materials 
WHERE compoundNumber = "input1"
   OR vendorCompoundNumber = "input2";
```

Based on the comments, it looks like you need to know which was matched as well. So this points back to a `UNION` statement, but with a small change from the other answer talking about this path

```
SELECT materialID, compoundNumber AS compoundDupFound, NULL as vendorCompoundDupFound
    FROM materials 
    WHERE compoundNumber = "input1"
UNION
SELECT materialID, NULL, vendorCompoundNumber AS vendorCompoundDupFound
    FROM materials 
    WHERE vendorCompoundNumber = "input2"
```

That should give you output as close as possible to the original question. This way you will get matched records or `NULL`, and then can tell which was matched.

Comment: yes, next I want the select result set to appear like in the original post.

Comment: I aliased the fields to match your example

Comment: Very close but the columns returned show the value of what's in the column, not a 1 or 0 (true or false). I would need to know if it's a match to the input, not the actual value. If it can't be done that's okay too

Comment: While it's possible to make it do that, why not simply accept that it returned a value? I mean, if you want to make sure it's not duplicate, you'll want this query to return no records.

Comment: The error message I display to the user will either be 1) Please fix compound number or 2) Please fix vendor compound number. Instead of performing 2 separate queries I thought I'd see if there was a clever way to combine them and learn more about mysql syntax in the process

Comment: Are these fields `NULL` if there is no value?

Comment: They are mandatory fields, so they won't have a null value. Database is set up to make sure new records can't be created without a value for both fields.

Comment: I had to borrow from the other question to get this, but I think my current edit should provide what you're looking for

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). If you do not want to check for duplicates - you need to use UNION ALL.

```
SELECT materialID FROM materials WHERE compoundNumber = "<some user input1>"
UNION 
SELECT materialID FROM materials WHERE vendorCompoundNumber = "<some user input2>"
```

Comment: +1 : Although this was marked down *(but no reason given)*, this pattern ***can*** actually substantially out-perform the use of `WHERE a = 'x' OR b = 'y'`.  This is because each of the two selects can use a different index; this is not the case in the `OR` based version.  As a result, the use of `OR` can result in a full-scan where as this version can result in two index-seeks.

Comment: Can I use this to somehow alias the columns as compoundDupFound and vendorCompoundDupFound each column in the result set showing if a match was found or not?

Comment: It is probably possible. If I understand you well (correct me if I don't), you want to count all duplicates? If yes, you should pick all duplicate records from your db, using UNION ALL/OR and actually count all duplicates using aggregation functions (COUNT).

Comment: Don't need to count, just see which column(s) (none, one, or both) was matched. I'll display specific error messages for each case which is why it would be nice to do it all in one.